# Anchor div to Bottom of Another div with and without overflow

Tags: css, overflow, anchor

I would like to anchor a div to the bottom of another div that has a fixed hight and has overflow:scroll applied to it but only if there is no overflow. If the div has overflow then I want the footer to got with the flow.

Currently the fiddle I have works if there is no overflow content. Once there is overflow then the footer overlaps the content and scrolls along from the 'bottom' position.

HTML:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:675px; text-align:left;">   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="height:100%;">
            <div class="content">
                <div >
                    content<br/>                
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    foot on the bottom unless overflow then stay within flow
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.content
{
    width:100%; 
    overflow:scroll; 
    overflow-x:hidden; 
    height:200px; 
    position: relative;
}

.footer
{
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

In order to see the problem, cut and paste the 'content' until it causes a content overflow.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZShsQ/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a pure CSS solution since the positioning of the footer is conditional i.e., position absolute when `.content`'s inner content is < 200px & normal flow/position relative when `.content`'s inner content is > 200px.

Here is a solution using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var contentHeight = $('.content').height();
    var overflowHeight = $('.content > div').height();

    if (overflowHeight > contentHeight) {
        $('.footer').css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'bottom': 0
        });
    } else {
        $('.footer').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'bottom': '10px'
        });
    }
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YmAgv/

Comment: I was hoping CSS had come far enough to handle this but your answer worked. Thanks.

Comment: Webkit has a solution called 'position: sticky', but it's not implemented in any other browser yet and hasn't made it in to a HTML/CSS spec. See here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

Comment: I saw that when I was searching the web for an answer but I wanted to see if CSS could do the trick. Your solution is a lot cleaner. The Webkit is overkill for what I needed to accomplish.

Comment: The proposed Webkit solution _is_ a simple, CSS-only solution. I think you may have skipped over that part of the article. Either way, glad to help out :)